# Button getting flashed for Angular ng-show in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, safari

I am showing and hiding button on page using ng-show angular directive. On page refresh, button is getting flashed even though it is disabled only in Safari browser. I have used ng-cloak for the button but still its not working only for Safari Browser. Please let me know if their is any solution for this.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code for the button and controller/directive setting the condition your using in ng-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various approaches:

1 - ng-cloak

2 - put angular script tag in head else browser has no idea what ng-cloak / ng-show means when rendering the page until angular has loaded (hence the flash)

3 - if all else fails use a boolean controller variable to control when the button is displayed - e.g. displayButton = false initially and then at some point in the controller set it to true and use the controller variable inside your ng-show - you might set it to true after all promises are resolved or might put a timeout on it.